# Changing remote of git does not work on digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, ssh, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a rails app on digital ocean, following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma). When I followed the exact steps, it worked perfectly. But then I realized the github repository is public. I should have it as private. I create a private repository and changed the remote origin in my local. I put the ssh keys in the new private repository. Removed the old apps folder in the server. And then tried to clone from the remote repository but it asks for password. (It should have taken the ssh key??).

Also I changed the deploy.rb and nginx.conf to reflect the changes of the remote repository and then gave this command, `cap production deploy:initial`, but it fails, due to authentication failure in git.

Why does it fail? Why is the ssh key not taking effect?

Comment: I have not used digitalocean but this can occur if you use the `https://github.com/...` adress instead of `git://`

Comment: You got any progress with this? Found a solution or still having the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because you have not enabled ssh forwarding for digital ocean? To verify, first edit the `$HOME/.ssh/config` on your local pc:

```
host *
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Now try to run `cap production deploy:initial`. If it works without a password now, then you should change the `host *` to actually match the hostname of your ssh host, so `ForwardAgent` is only set for digital ocean:

```
host digitalocean.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

For your use case: `ForwardAgent` enables the server to use your local ssh keys, so your deploy user has the same "ssh rights" like your local user.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `capistrano` is still using the old git remote address. When you change the remote url, it is not enough to do this inside `deploy.rb` etc, but you have to manually change the file `repo/config` inside the deployment dir of capistrono on the server when you already deployed it with an old remote url before.

So, if you have the following inside your `deploy.rb` (or `deploy/production.rb`)

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/path/to/deploy'
```

You have to manually edit the **file on the server**

```
/var/www/path/to/deploy/repo/config
```

and amend the `url = XXX` entry of your remote to match the new one.

Comment: The set deploy to is set this way - `set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"`

Comment: `user` and `application` must have been declared before with `set` then, too.

Comment: Yup, I actually changed the repository name also and hence the application name but forgot to change it in the set application. but even then it asks for password while cloning. or using capistrano

Comment: On your local machine it does not ask when cloning but when you run `cap production deploy:initial`?

Comment: On local git clone works. On server git clone asks for password even though ssh key is set. On local when I run cap production deploy:initial it fails because of authentication failure.

Comment: OK, see my other answer - next shot ;-)